# Macro VBA copy paste when worksheets have empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

My task is to copy and paste from many different worksheets into 1 common worksheet. The problem arises when the cells for my copy worksheets are empty( The copied cells will be my headers instead). Could anyone provide me to code to not copy anything over when the worksheet cells are blank? My code is below:

```
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

Sheets("SEA-Weekly New Opp").Select
Range("A4:N1000").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

Workbooks.Open "Z:\SFDC Reporting\MSIA(PENANG,ESTEROL,TAMPOI) Reporting Template.xlsm", 
Password:="Mingsee"

Set wsCopy = Workbooks("MSIA(PENANG,ESTEROL,TAMPOI) Reporting Template.xlsm").Worksheets("New Opps")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("CY All OPS APAC WORKING FILE MACRO WORKING FILE - 
Copy.xlsm").Worksheets("SEA-Weekly New Opp")


lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row



wsCopy.Range("A2:N" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("A4")

Workbooks("MSIA(PENANG,ESTEROL,TAMPOI) Reporting Template.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True

Workbooks.Open "Z:\SFDC Reporting\MSIA(Plentong) Reporting Template.xlsm", Password:="Phyllis"



Set wsCopy = Workbooks("MSIA(Plentong) Reporting Template.xlsm").Worksheets("New Opps")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("CY All OPS APAC WORKING FILE MACRO WORKING FILE - 
Copy.xlsm").Worksheets("SEA-Weekly New Opp")


lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row


wsCopy.Range("A2:N" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)


Workbooks("MSIA(PLENTONG) Reporting Template.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True

Workbooks.Open "Z:\SFDC Reporting\INDONESIA Reporting Template.xlsm", Password:="Melinda"


Set wsCopy = Workbooks("INDONESIA Reporting Template.xlsm").Worksheets("New Opps")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("CY All OPS APAC WORKING FILE MACRO WORKING FILE - 
Copy.xlsm").Worksheets("SEA-Weekly New Opp")


lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row


wsCopy.Range("A2:N" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)

Workbooks("INDONESIA Reporting Template.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True

Workbooks.Open "Z:\SFDC Reporting\PHILIPPINES Reporting Template.xlsm", Password:="Janet"
```

Comment: Maybe check if `lCopyLastRow = 2`? Or maybe `=1` if your headers are in row 1.

Comment: Just tried for both 1 and 2. Gives me an "application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your revised attempt. What row are your headers in?

Comment: they are from A1 to N1

Comment: `If lCopyLastRow > 1 Then`, `wsCopy.Range("A2:N" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _ wsDest.Range("A4")`, `End If`.

Comment: Doesn't work though, cant seem to get the code to run